# When Abroad, How To Stop Annoying "Cellular Network Not Found" Popup Prompt?

Tags: wi-fi, notifications, carriers, airplane-mode

"Cellular Network Not Found" is that annoying message I get when out of range of my carrier, but what will I do if I am abroad and don't plan on using roaming? I don't want this message popping into my face every 10 seconds. How will I use phone's camera if this annoying message will keep on persisting? Switch **"Airplane Mode"** you say? Well what if I decide to access internet through Wi-Fi? Still I will probably see this popup.

Is there a way to disable annoying message **without** enabling "Airplane Mode" still being able to take camera shots and surf the internet?

*HTC Desire S*
*Android 2.3.5*

Comment: On most phones you can still enable Wi-Fi while in airplane mode. In fact, many airlines [now have Wi-Fi in flight](http://www.portfolio.com/business-travel/2009/03/13/Airlines-With-WiFi-Service). Airplane mode might be a more viable option than you think ;)

Comment: @jlehenbauer that should be an answer...

Answer (score 4):

On most phones you can still **enable Wi-Fi while in airplane mode**. In fact, many airlines [now have Wi-Fi in flight](http://www.portfolio.com/business-travel/2009/03/13/Airlines-With-WiFi-Service). Airplane mode might be a more viable option than you think ;)

Comment: At least with Cyanogenmod it's: Enable airplane mode, then switch back on wifi (or bluetooth)

Comment: I believe it was on my Stock Sense as well.

Comment: Turn on airplane mode then turn on wifi is standard on the devices I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off just the cell radio by using the `Phone Info` feature: dial `*#*#4636#*#*` and press `Turn off radio`.